# In Haskell, find the smallest element satisfying a condition

Tags: haskell

Suppose P is a condition involving natural numbers. How can I find in Haskell the smallest natural number n such that P(n) is true ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried to solve this problem? [ask]

Answer (score 4):

It depends on `P`. The naive approach is just scanning from 0, but it might be too slow depending on `P`.

```
p :: Int -> Bool
p n = ... --- Your condition

v :: Int
v = head $ filter p [0..]
```

Comment: Thank you, snak. That works and answers my question. Actually, it is rather independent from p and works fine for my particular p.